# Excel - Extract All Dates from Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have the following cases:

```
Today's Date is 08/20/2020 and tomorrow's date is 30/10/2018. Status = N/A
Yesterday's Date status is stuff/things but it  is 2020/08/31 and today is 8/20/18.
```

What I want to return is

```
08/20/2020, 30/10/2018
2020/08/31, 08/20/18
```

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: You can do this in a formula or do you mean use vba?

Comment: Use find() and look for the "/", then left() mid() and right() as necessary

Comment: That doesn't work because there are other values that use the "/" etc, for example "N/A"

Comment: Edited post to reflect this

Comment: VBA seems like the natural solution. Unfortunately, the Excel worksheet formula language is weak for text processing. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/4996248) for how to do this in Excel.

Comment: Is each line a single cell? How's the data presenting in Excel?

Comment: Correct, each line is in a single cell, so "A1" = first row and "B1" = second row

Comment: All values are contained into those cells, there is no spill over into "A2", "A3", etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TEXTJOIN in an array formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*/*/*",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($1:$25)-1)*99+1,99)))),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($1:$25)-1)*99+1,99)),"")),".","")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel

[image]

---

If you do not have Office 365 then the output will need to be in different cells for each "date"

Put this in B1, copy over and down:

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$25)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*/*/*",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($1:$25)-1)*99+1,99))))),COLUMN(A:A))-1)*99+1,99)),".",""),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't have any luck with this, if it helps, I'm using 100 records. I am also using the correct version of excel

Comment: @LunchBox I do not know what you mean by: `I didn't have any luck with this`.  Please be more specific.  As you can see it works for me, so I have not idea where to start helping you resolve the issue.

Comment: @LunchBox Are you sure you used CNTRL+SHFT+ENTER  instead of just ENTER when you finished the formula?  You will know you did it right when you see { } around the formula in the formula bar.  These { } cannot be added manually.

Comment: Originally, due to a time crunch, I was going to try to manipulate this in Excel but I couldn't get this to work for me. I am aware of how to add the brackets though. I just said screw it and did it in python. I am going to mark this as the answer so you get the points, but I just couldn't get it to work and solved this in python.